# Is there a way to compute the empty area between a group of touching polygons?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

Given a bunch of convex polygons layed out like a house truss, is there a way to compute the empty area, or get a polygon for each of those "holes" between the polygons?

[image]

I tried starting from any given polygon and then finding the intersections between some of the lines of the polygons and somehow I'm stuck at how to properly select which lines to use for the intersections.

I then tried to verify for a clockwise detection of the area but it seem that my algo for determining the CW/CCW of two lines does not work as, I think, it act as if the lines have the same origin instead of being "in sequence" from each other.

Comment: You might calculate the area of the big triangle and deduct the area of the beams.

Comment: @MarkBennet That would be a solution if I wanted the sum of all the "holes", however I want the area from each hole separately.

Comment: Cross-posted from [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22391630/1468366) which has an answer by now.

Comment: Given a hole $\mathscr{H}_\epsilon$ which is itself a convex polygon. Assume you know the polygon $\mathscr{P}$ formed by the center lines of the surrounding beams and all the beams have same thickness $2\epsilon$. If $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are the angles of $\mathscr{P}$, then the area of the hole $\mathscr{H}_\epsilon$ will be given be $$\text{Area}(\mathscr{H}_\epsilon) = \text{Area}(\mathscr{P}) - \epsilon\;\text{Perimeter}(\mathscr{P}) + \epsilon^2 \sum_{i=1}^n\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_i}{2}\right)$$
Does this help?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to calculate the area of a triangle ?

Comment: @achillehui It is possible to have a concave hole in some cases (not from my example though).

Comment: @achillehui Also, the beams do not have the same thickness.

Comment: The limitation of convexity is pretty easy to bypass. However, if the beams doesn't have the same thickness, the formula will become messy. You probably need to follow the advice on the solution on MO.